# vertex array objects in android opengl-es

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex-array-object

I heard most of the android devices that are recently released support VAOs of opengl-es. I am trying to develop an app on a opengl-es 2.0 environment. However, I am wondering

(Q1)Do most of the Android devices being used(produced maybe several years ago) support VAOs? if not wouldn't be better not to use VAOs because we'll have to write seperate codes for devices that support VAOs and and those who don't

(Q2)And does it really give us a great advantage in performance (compared to just using vertex buffer objects(VBO) only)to adobt them? if so how could we use them in a opengl-es2.0 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the capability database at [delphigl.de](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gles_launchpad.php) (*), 65% of all devices they have data for support the [GL_OES_vertex_array_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_array_object.txt) extension, as of May 22, 2015, with data for 459 devices.

Note that this is a percentage of device **models**, not a percentage of device **units** sold.

If you sort the extension list by coverage, it clocks in on place 16 of all extensions. So I think it would be fair to say that the extension is widely supported, but **not** universally available.

You can certainly check for the extension at runtime, and use different code paths. Is it worth it? That obviously depends on the use case, and you'll need to test and compare it yourself to be certain.

My feeling is that it probably won't help much for most use cases. Particularly if you want to support devices that are a few years old, many of them won't have very powerful GPUs. VAOs help reduce the CPU overhead for vertex setup, but that's unlikely to be very significant if you're limited by GPU fragment processing, which will often be the case for graphics intensive applications.

The case would be different if you were looking at desktop systems, where modern high end GPUs have gotten so powerful that almost anything you do can quickly become a bottleneck.

You might be better off spending your time on more generic performance optimizations. Make sure that your draw calls are big enough, don't change state more frequently than needed, etc.

But of course, as I mentioned, if you have the time/resources, testing and comparing is always the best approach.

(*) I have no association to this web site, except as a user.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice!! come to think of it my app won't even be that graphic intensive... guess i should focus more on other aspects